# AppleScript Dialog gives error?

Tags: applescript

My AppleScript app on my computer gives a error.

Here is the code:

```
set file to display dialog "Open Script?" default answer "tests/helloworld.in"
do shell script "cat " & file & " | python parenthetic.py"
do shell script "echo"
do shell script "echo App +" & file  & "+ is done load!"
```

And the error:

> Can't set file to display dialog "Open Script?" default answer "tests/helloworld.in". Access not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set `file` because it's reserved by AppleScript.

Rename `file` to something else, such as `myfile`.